# What emoji plugin should I use: HTML or Image?

Tags: plugins

I have two plugins to choose from. It will be used on a forum type script. I like the idea of HTML emojis (i.e.  `&#128515;`), however, each device is going to show their own styles and some devices (ipads as an example) do not render some HTML emojis.

With image emojis (i.e. `<img class="emojis" src="/img/smiling_face.png">`) there will be uniformity across all devices and browsers.

I am still not sure what to choose. If it was up to you, what would you use for your forum?

Comment: Go with the image.  In my opinion, there is nothing worse than seeing a group of square boxes, since my browser can't render some of the Emojis.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Do you think there are still plenty of people out there using older computers / browsers?

Comment: Assuredly there are. I'm writing this from a Windows 7 machine now, but don't trick yourself into thinking that supporting older tech will make your content accessible to more people. Unless you put in the effort for alt text and are very consistent screen readers will probably do much worse with image-based.

Comment: Answers to this question might be pretty opinionated, but I'm glad you asked @Alex333 because I think this is a good learning opportunity for internet accessibility.

Comment: The one I will be using works on Windows 7. Tested it. HTML emojis are not supported by Windows 7+. Windows 9 is where it starts. Not sure though.